# Unity - how to make object glow in gradient?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lighting, glow

Alright, Im having a problem and Ive looked through Unity forums but cant find a working solution. I need to make an object glow from the outer into the center in a gradient, like this - [image]

I am trying to recreate glowing windows like this - [image]

Meaning it looks like the light is coming in from the other side. Im making my models in qubicle and tried at first doing a gradient, but this didn't create desired effect and wasn't glowing:

[image]

I then went and made my objects glow using the Bloom script on my camera, however this did not effect the actual INSIDE color of the "window", only made a halo AROUND them -

[image]

I know this probably requires shaders/or a light script, but I have absolutely no idea how to accomplish this. How can I make an object glow from the out inwards? Is this possible?

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to look at the `Emission` parameter of the Standard material. Here, you will be able to set an emissive texture : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterEmission.html

Comment: No, that is what I have creating the bloom effect now and it doesn't affect the inside of the object just outside - see my edit for specifics

Comment: Try to add an **emission texture** of a gradient with a white color.

Comment: Sorry, how would I do that? Im really new to shaders/textures. Is that the same as a material?

Comment: Take a look at the link in my first comment. When selecting your window material, in the inspector, at the left of the `Emission` label, you can specify an emission map. Every non-black pixel of the texture will emit the given color. Thus, try to add your gradient texture here.